# I need a jquery slider with vertical thumbnail and text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm developing a site for a client that need to use a slider similar to this flash one :
http://www.flashxml.net/media-slideshow.html

The slider should have a **vertical navigation** contains **both** slide image and title

Is there is a jquery plugin that looks like it with minimum customization effort.

I search google for one and I checked most on codecanyon too I found wooslider but it only show image thumbnail and no text .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found one here " [All in one Banner](http://www.responsivejqueryslider.com/playlist_banner_skin_elegant_effect_random.html)" cost $10 and also a free one but not responsive [here](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/28/Featured-Content-Slider-Using-jQuery)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-1

Comment: No , you didn't check the flash link I added .

Comment: I need a vertical thumbnails with title text inside thumbnail area.

Comment: Couldn't you try customizing `bxslider` to fit what you're looking for?

Comment: I tried that and when I change thumbnail width to include the slide title I got a bad layout of slides